# STIX Two font: \emph inside italic text not working as expected

Tags: fonts, stix

I have found that using the STIX Two font, the command `\emph` inside an italic text is not working.

```
% STIX Two font
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{STIX2Text}[
  Extension       = .otf,
  UprightFont     = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont      = *-Italic,
  BoldFont        = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldItalic ]

\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
\textit{One two three. \emph{Four five.} \textnormal{Six seven.}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

> *One two three. Four five.* Six seven.

If working properly then the expected output should be:

> *One two three.* Four five. Six seven.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

**Update**: I'm using XeLaTeX in TeX Live 2015 under Linux Mint 18.3 (equivalent to Ubuntu 16.04).

TeXstudio screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Don't use `mathspec` along with `unicode-math` to begin with.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Tested without `mathspec` and the output is the same. I have removed it from the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I can't reproduce: I get “*One two three.* Four five. Six Seven.”

Comment: @egreg Strange. I have tested again and I am sure about the result. I forgot to mention that I'm using XeLaTeX in TeX Live 2015 under Ubuntu 16.04. Please see the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, TeX Live 2015! Three years behind!

Comment: @egreg I once tried upgrading to the latest version but then after the upgrade it was not usable, got some conflict errors at compilation :(

Comment: I have installed the TUG provided TeX Live 2017 on several virtual machines running various flavors of GNU/Linux, including Mint 18. I might try also with TL 2018 on this architecture, but I see no reason for it not to work.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the information. Since my attempt to upgrade TeX Live on my office desktop failed (I could not even re-install the 2015 version, and now TeX is not usable on that machine), I did not think about upgrading it anymore on other machines. But I'll spend some time in the next days trying again to install TeX Live 2018.

Comment: @egreg I installed TeX Live 2018 but then cannot use external fonts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434032/how-to-install-opentype-fonts-for-tex-live-2018 Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with TeX Live 2015. Not with TeX Live 2016 or later.

Update your TeX distribution.