# How to install OpenType fonts for TeX Live 2018?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I have installed TeX Live 2018 from the .iso file, along side with my old TeX Live 2015 installed using `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` on Linux Mint. When compiling a XeLaTeX document that uses the STIX Two font:

```
% STIX Two font
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{STIX2Text}[
  Extension       = .otf,
  UprightFont     = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont      = *-Italic,
  BoldFont        = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldItalic ]

\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}
```

I got a "font-not-found" error.

I tried copying the *.otf files to `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix2` but the fonts is still not recognized by the new TeX Live.

Previously for TeX Live 2015, I had just to copy the above `stix2` folder to `/usr/share/fonts/opentype`. The folder is still there but TeX Live 2018 cannot recognize it either.

Any suggestions please?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Issue `sudo cp $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf 
/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf` and then `sudo fc-cache -fsv`

Comment: @egreg Thanks, but that did not help :(

Comment: @egreg I removed TeX Live 2015, then opened tlmgr gui to rebuild symlinks and font maps, and it works now.